# Remove leaflet watermark, but no OpenStreetMap copyright logo

Tags: r, r-leaflet

I'm wanting to remove the leaflet watermark, without removing the OpenStreetMaps copyright logo.

```
leaflet() %>% 
  addTiles() %>% 
  setView(-93.65, 42.0285, zoom = 17)
```

Yields:

[image]

However, I want:

[image]

Just the ©OpenStreetMap logo.

```
leaflet(
  options = leafletOptions(
    attributionControl = FALSE)
) %>% 
  addTiles() %>% 
  setView(-93.65, 42.0285, zoom = 17)
```

Gets rid of everything. Is there an approach that isn't all-or-nothing?